# Cakephp Model is not linking up to all fields of its table

Tags: cakephp, webforms

I have a PHP application which I have developed on my local machine and have recently put up onto the server.

All has been working fine until I created a few new fields in one of my database tables. They are boolean (tinyInt1) so in the add/edit forms I get a check box.

These fields were created after having made the site live so I created them at the same time on both my local machine and the server. The application on my local machine finds these new fields and '*automagically*' creates check boxes on my forms, but on the server it is as if the model isn't detecting that these fields in exist in the table.

I used:

```
print_r($this->Model->getColumnTypes());
```

to confirm this, and sure enough the model on the server doesn't seem to know about these new fields, even though on my local machine it does.

I'm a bit stumped on this one. I've been using CakePHP for a while but I'm no expert so I'm sure that I must just be overlooking something...

EDIT: Solved it. Setting debug to 1 on the server fixed caused the model to start fetching all the data from the new database fields.

Comment: show model Accommodation and its associative table

Answer (score 2):

Clear your model cache. Files in `app/tmp/cache/models/` folder.

Comment: Great, print_r($this->Model->getColumnTypes()); now shows that the fields are linked up, but when I try to echo out the values of those fields I get 'Undefined Index'

Comment: Well probably you are doing some other mistake. Can't really say without knowing how/what you are fetching and how are you using that data.

Comment: In the controller: `$this->set('accommodations', $this->Accommodation->find('all'));`, doing a print of 'accommodations' shows that the data of the new fields isn't a part of the data that is returned by `find`. I have also cleared the model cache folder several times.

Comment: Is the new field shown when you do `debug($this->Accomodation->schema())`?